# answering questions on mi.yodeya on Chol Hamoed

Tags: internet, melacha-creative-work, chol-hamoed, stackexchange

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Typing on Chol Hamoed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/typing-on-chol-hamoed)

Is answering questions on mi.yodeya.com considered working therby making it assur to go on the website on chol hamod

Comment: Any specific melacha you're thinking of? If it's writing see: http://mi.yodeya.com/questions/3035/typing-on-chol-hamoed

Comment: And if the answer is indeed no, how can the person post it???

Comment: Is asking questions on mi.yodeya.com considered working therby making it assur to go on the website on chol hamod

Comment: yydl, he can post the question because it is directly relevant to chol hamoed.