# Asking/Answering non-Chag-related questions on Mi.Yodeya during Chol Hamoed

Tags: internet, melacha-creative-work, chagim-holidays, chol-hamoed

I don't know the Chol Hamoed laws at all well, but my [impression](http://www.askmoses.com/en/article/207,2156797/What-types-of-labor-are-permitted-on-Chol-Hamoed.html) is that practical/avoda- and melacha-type stuff that is not either related to the holiday, nor done to prevent loss, is generally forbidden.

Would asking and answering questions on StackExchange (Mi.Yodeya or elsewhere) that are not related to the holiday be a violation of this prohibition? Might the idea that using Mi.Yodeya, at least, is, in some sense, Torah learning, be a competing factor?

Related: [answering questions on mi.yodeya on Chol Hamoed](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/6932/answering-questions-on-mi-yodeya-on-chol-hamoed)

Comment: Duplicate of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/typing-on-chol-hamoed?

Comment: @msh210 Absolutely not