# How does the prohibition of writing during chol hamoed apply for electronic devices?

Tags: melacha-creative-work, chol-hamoed

There is a prohibition for writing during chol hamoed, with a few exceptions such as in cases where loss would be involved.

How does the prohibition of writing during chol hamoed apply for writing / typing in electronic devices, such as cellphones and computers?

Comment: You write with a cellphone? You mean like a printer? Or a stylus-pen? Please clarify your question.

Comment: @DoubleAA clarified

Comment: How do you write in electronic devices?

Comment: It seems that this had been asked before here:  http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/typing-on-chol-hamoed