# Can one play computer games on Chol Hamoed

Tags: halacha, sources-mekorot, chol-hamoed

I know that there is a [debate](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/3035/typing-on-chol-hamoed/57127#57127) among the poskim as to whether one can type on Chol Hamoed.

Does anyone discuss whether one can play computer games on Chol Hamoed?

Answer (score 4):

Rabbi Cohen addresses it in his [Dose of Halacha](http://doseofhalacha.blogspot.co.uk/2013/09/computers-on-chol-hamoed.html) (the article you quoted in the question!). After discussing whether one may type, etc. on Chol Hamoed, he writes:

> While the Acharonim don’t discuss playing computer games, it seems that it should be [muttar](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/591) as, like driving to an outing, it can be considered relevant to the Chag and no [Issur](//meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/585) is involved.

Comment: As a non-Jew I normally am able to find any terminology using a simple Google search, however *muttar* is one of the terms I have not been able to find. Would anybody be so kind and explain or link the meaning of the term?

Comment: @DavidMulder Good now?

Comment: @msh210 Thank you very much, normally alternative spellings like that (muttar vs mutar) are suggested by Google, but this one was not (at least for me). Much appreciated and didn't know about the glossary, so that's very nice to see as well.